# How convert from trait with type member to case class with type parameter an viceversa

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, typeclass

I don't know how to solve a problem in scala. Maybe someone can help me!

I have a case class (`Operation`) with some type parameter, this class can be returned by a method that know nothing about the parameter types (example a parser from `string`/`json`/`xml`).

So I need a way to transform from `ShadowedOperation` to `Operation` in some way, because the need is to parse from some data a `ShadowedOperation` and from this extract the typed version (an `Operation`).

I've write a code that should express the problem, it's simplified and try to do something different, but if this can be solved I can solve also the real need.

Probably with `shapeless` there is a solution, but I need to find a solution without it.

```
object box {

  trait Transform[A, B] {
    def apply(in: A): B
  }
  object Transform {
    def instance[A, B](f: A => B): Transform[A, B] = new Transform[A, B] {
      override def apply(in: A): B = f(in)
    }
  }

  implicit class TransformOps[T](w: T) {
    def transform(implicit t: Transform[T, String]) = t(w)
  }

  trait ShadowedOperation {
    type I
    type O
    def param: String
    def otherParam: Int
    def in: I
    def out: O
  }

  object ShadowedOperation {
    // How can i do this in a generic, typed and wonderful way ???
    implicit def operationToString: Transform[ShadowedOperation, String] = ???
  }

  case class Operation[I0, O0](
    param: String,
    otherParam: Int,
    in: I0,
    out: O0
  ) extends ShadowedOperation {type I = I0; type O = O0}

  object Operation {
    implicit def operationToString[I, O](
      implicit
      iToString: Transform[I, String],
      oToString: Transform[O, String]
    ): Transform[Operation[I, O], String] =
      Transform.instance(in => s"${in.otherParam} - ${in.param} - ${iToString(in.in)} - ${oToString(in.out)}")
  }

  def fakeParseFromString(in: String): List[ShadowedOperation] = {
    // this simulate a parsing (or read from db) from string to extract the case class
    List(Operation("param", 0, "in!", "out!"), Operation("param", 0, "in!", 100))
  }

}


object Main extends App {

  import box._

  implicit val intToString: Transform[Int, String] = Transform.instance(_.toString)
  implicit val stringToString: Transform[String, String] = Transform.instance(_.toString)

  val op = Operation("param", 0, "in!", "out!")
  val shadowedOperationList = fakeParseFromString("imagine that this string contain a json")
  val opString = op.transform
  val shadowedOpString = shadowedOperationList.map(_.transform)
  println(opString)
  println(shadowedOpString)
}
```

Thanks in advance to all who can help!

Answer (score 1):

I made several changes:

- added covariance/contravariance to `Transform[-A, +B]`
- introduced type `ShadowedOperation.Aux[I0, O0]`
- fixed returning type of `fakeParseFromString` using `Aux`-type
- lifted `operationToString` from companion object of case class to companion object of trait with corresponding changes
- imported instance: `import op._`

The whole code:

```
  object box {

    trait Transform[-A, +B] {
      def apply(in: A): B
    }
    object Transform {
      def instance[A, B](f: A => B): Transform[A, B] = new Transform[A, B] {
        override def apply(in: A): B = f(in)
      }
    }

    implicit class TransformOps[T](w: T) {
      def transform(implicit t: Transform[T, String]) = t(w)
    }

    trait ShadowedOperation {
      type I
      type O
      def param: String
      def otherParam: Int
      def in: I
      def out: O

      implicit def operationToString(
                                      implicit
                                      iToString: Transform[I, String],
                                      oToString: Transform[O, String]
                                    ): Transform[ShadowedOperation.Aux[I, O], String] =
        Transform.instance(in => s"${in.otherParam} - ${in.param} - ${iToString(in.in)} - ${oToString(in.out)}")
    }

    object ShadowedOperation {
      type Aux[I0, O0] = ShadowedOperation { type I = I0; type O = O0 }
    }

    case class Operation[I0, O0](
                                  param: String,
                                  otherParam: Int,
                                  in: I0,
                                  out: O0
                                ) extends ShadowedOperation {type I = I0; type O = O0}


    def fakeParseFromString[I, O](in: Operation[I, O]): ShadowedOperation.Aux[I, O] = in

  }




  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import box._

    implicit val intToString: Transform[Int, String] = Transform.instance(_.toString)
    implicit val stringToString: Transform[String, String] = Transform.instance(_.toString)

    val op = Operation("param", 0, "in!", "out!")
    val shadowedOperation = fakeParseFromString(op)
    import op._
    val opString = op.transform
    val shadowedOpString = shadowedOperation.transform
    println(opString)//0 - param - in! - out!
    println(shadowedOpString)//0 - param - in! - out!
  }
```

So `shapeless` isn't necessary here.

---

When you write just `ShadowedOperation` instead of `ShadowedOperation.Aux[???, ???]` you loose some information about types. You have to find a way to restore this information about `I`, `O` (some casting, specifying types explicitly, defining more implicits etc.). Otherwise implicits won't work.

For instance in your updated example you can write

```
def fakeParseFromString(in: String): List[ShadowedOperation.Aux[String, Any]] = 
  List(Operation("param", 0, "in!","out!"), Operation("param", 0, "in!", 100))

implicit val anyToString: Transform[Any, String] = Transform.instance(_.toString)
val shadowedOpString = shadowedOperationList.map(_.transform)
println(shadowedOpString) 
// List(Operation(param,0,in!,out!), Operation(param,0,in!,100))
```

Comment: Thanks for you response! The problem is that the real `fakeParseFromString` can't infer types (`I` and `O`) from function argument. I've change the examlpe to explain better the question